# JSON array fetch using JS

Tags: javascript, json

I wanted some help with JSON fetching using JS, I'm working a library of images and I have a locally present json file which includes over 5000+ entries of images name, size, color and etc for clothing articles. I was able to fetch the images by doing this,

JS

```
fetch("dataset_api.json")
    .then(function (data) {
        return data.json();
    })


    .then(function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            var img = (data[i].images[1, 0, 2, 3].src)
            $(".app-right").append("<div class='grid' data-id= " + i + "> <img src=" + img + " class='imggrd' loading=lazy> </div>");
        }
```

Example of a json entry

```
dataset_api.json


color: "black"
desc: "Shirt by Sixth June"
gender: "male"
images: (4) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
retailPrice: 87
size: (4) ['S', 'M', 'L', 'XL']
title: "SHIRT"
url: "url"
..................
```

and append it in the HTML it self

..but the issue I'm facing right now is, I think the json has so many entries that It automatically converts them into batches of 100 so [0 to 99]

[image: screenshot console]

and so on, so If I want to get the next batch of images I have to change the value for " i " in the for loop in js to 99 or above to do that.

I was wondering if there is a way so that as soon as a user scroll to the bottom the JS automatically loads the next batch right after by the increment of 100.
Also the main reason I'm not loading all the images at once is because it is really heavy for the machine to do so.

HTML

```
    <div class="app-right">
    </div>
```

Comment: the batches are only in your browser console for easier navigation

Comment: That "batching" is just how it gets displayed, just like `images: (4) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]` is not actually containing `...` in any of the data.

Comment: The data of dataset_api.json doesn't look like JSON? Or did you simplify it?

Comment: `data[i].images[1, 0, 2, 3].src` is not a thing that you can do in JavaScript to get 4 array items. This will is not a syntax error, but it will only get you 1 item.

Comment: Also, it does not "convert them into batches". That's just how they will be displayed on the browser console for performance reasons. The actual data does not change.

Answer (score 0):

You actually get back an array of objects (as in your image attached), 5973 of them.

The `[0 ... 99]` etc is just easier for us to expand so that the expanded result is not huge.

To do what you wanted, you can look into what is called "infinite scroll". You can

1. Find a way to let the API to return you data in chucks, such as 50 each time, and do the infinite scroll
2. Fetch all data all at once, and only show more to the user when the user scroll down